# json data not assigning to input box

Tags: javascript, json, model-view-controller

i have a product function in model that function returns the json data of product id,name,price of single product i have successfully send as json and in page load the data showing ,in console option product name is also shown but in assinging
product price input box the rate of price is not showing can anyone help

```
<td><select name="prdid">' + optionProduct + '</select></td><td><input name=" Price " class=" Price" ></td>
  $.get('@Url.Content("~")Home/GetProductDetails')
             .done(function (salesProductData) {                

                 /****** product Name Addeing *********/
                 optionProduct = "";
                 $.each(salesProductData, function (i, value) {                    
                     optionProduct += "<option value='" + value.prdid + "'>" + value.prdname + "</option>";
                     $('input[name="Price"]').val(salesProductData.prdRate);
                 });               
                 console.log(salesProductData);
```

json data

```
1.  Array(4)
1.  0:{prdname: "wire", prdid: 1, prdRate: 20}
2.  1:{prdname: "cone", prdid: 2, prdRate: 30}
3.  2:{prdname: "product1", prdid: 3, prdRate: 50}
4.  3:{prdname: "product2", prdid: 4, prdRate: 20}
5.  length:4
```

Comment: `salesProductData` is a collection - it does not have a property named `prdRate` (but each item in the collection does contain a property named `prdRate`). And why are you setting the value of a single textbox in a loop (you would keep overwriting the value and only the last value would be displayed)

Comment: how can i get the result of product rate to  input box shall use option change function

Comment: Not clear what your asking. Are you saying that if you select say the 2nd option, then you want to update the value of the textbox to show 30 (and if you select the 3rd optio, you want it to display 50)?

Comment: yes that is what i want

Comment: Then you would need to store `salesProductData` in a global variable, and use javascript to handle the change event of the `<select>` and look up the value in the array based on the selected option

Comment: thanks i will try it if u post a sample it will be useful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to access the index since **salesProductData** is an array

```
$('input[name="Price"]').val(salesProductData[i].prdRate);
```

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
    at Object.<anonymous> (index:240)

Comment: try accessing  $('input[name="Price"]').val(value.prdRate);